# Rearrange date format in SQL using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

I have activation_date column with date format `YYYY-DD-MM` in my DB.
I need to replace all values to the following format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
This is what I tried so far but it's not changing anything.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(activation_date, '^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$', '\\1-\\3-\\2') FROM 
Warranties WHERE activation_date != ''
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `activation_date`?

Comment: Its defined as a string

Comment: It is usually better to do the conversion to DATE or DATETIME as the data is being INSERTed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
select str_to_date(activation_date, '%Y-%d-%m')
```

This returns a date.  I see no reason to convert this back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

`YYYY` has four characters but you have used `\d{2}`. You just need to replace `\d{2}` by `\d{4}`.

```
^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSrzKV/1)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concatenating individual parts of the string since all the formatting functions do not work on a String. Here is the code:

`UPDATE Warranties SET activation_date = concat(SUBSTRING(activation_date,1,4),'-',SUBSTRING(activation_date,9,2),'-',SUBSTRING(activation_date,6,2)) WHERE activation_date != ''`